# javac Jenkins Ant: build errors relating to dependent import.jars

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, javac

I am having trouble building my Java src code via a Jenkins project using Ant. I am getting code from Git, then invoking an ant build.xml to build the src in a .class and then .jar.  Simple enough, eh ?!!!  When I build the Jenkins project, I get errors that I am pretty sure pertain to dependent libraries not being notice by Ant (doesn't like my exception chaining in my catch, or says my file is missing a ';' or ')', or 'illegal start of type'... over 100 errors... All this src runs fine in my Eclipse IDE, so what is up ?!!

Ant build file :

```
'<project name="testcasecompile" default="dist" basedir=".">
  <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
        <classpath id="classpath">
                <pathelement location="/home/jon/Downloads/Jenkins_Test_Helpers/taf-dependent-jars/testng-6.5.2.jar/" />
            <pathelement location="/home/jon/Downloads/Jenkins_Test_Helpers/taf-dependent-jars/" />
            <pathelement location="/home/jon/Downloads/Jenkins_Test_Helpers/" />
            <path>   
                <fileset dir="/home/jon/Downloads/Jenkins_Test_Helpers/">   
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </path>
        </classpath>    
    </taskdef>
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/"/>
  <property name="build" location="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/testcasecompile-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>'
```

JENKINS BUILD LOG:

```
'Started by user [8mha:AAAAih+LCAAAAAAAAABb85aBtbiIQSajNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc+jsiC1KCczL9svvyT1dMUiOWdZ/mImBiZPBrac1Lz0kgwfBubSopwSBiGfrMSyRP2cxLx0/eCSosy8dOuKIgYpNOOcITTIMAYIYGRiYKgoADI4Sxi49EuLU4v080pzcgCbGluCjwAAAA==[0manonymous
ln -s 2012-08-02_15-43-13 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/builds/17 failed: -1 
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@55a92d3a
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 81e259a7303d32c923511c3118b756c08e648ae3 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from /git/arcus/automation/tests/functional/
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision 81e259a7303d32c923511c3118b756c08e648ae3 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision 81e259a7303d32c923511c3118b756c08e648ae3 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/test/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin/ant -file testcase_compile.xml
Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcase_compile.xml

[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAABb85aBtbiIQT6jNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjGvRM8xryQksSg9tcQvvyTVvqNr/s+Vl9uYGBgqihikoKqT8/OK83NS9ZwhNEghAwQwghQWAADROOumXQAAAA==[0minit:

[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAABb85aBtbiIQT6jNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjGvRM8xryQksSg9tcQvvyTVvqNr/s+Vl9uYGBgqihikoKqT8/OK83NS9ZwhNEghAwQwghQWAADROOumXQAAAA==[0mcompile:
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcase_compile.xml:32: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 16 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:64: <identifier> expected
    [javac]         } catch (InterruptedException | IOException | BrowserOpenException
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:64: '{' expected
    [javac]         } catch (InterruptedException | IOException | BrowserOpenException
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:64: illegal start of expression
    [javac]         } catch (InterruptedException | IOException | BrowserOpenException
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:64: ';' expected
    [javac]         } catch (InterruptedException | IOException | BrowserOpenException
    [javac]                                                                           ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:65: ';' expected
    [javac]                 | UnableToCreateProfileException e) {
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:68: 'catch' without 'try'
    [javac]         } catch (Exception e) {
    [javac]           ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:68: ')' expected
    [javac]         } catch (Exception e) {
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:68: not a statement
    [javac]         } catch (Exception e) {
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:68: ';' expected
    [javac]         } catch (Exception e) {
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:78: illegal start of type
    [javac]     public void site1clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:78: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site1clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:78: ')' expected
    [javac]     public void site1clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:78: not a statement
    [javac]     public void site1clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:78: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site1clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:79: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map1zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:79: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map1zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:79: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map1zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:79: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map1zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:79: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map1zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:79: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map1zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:80: not a statement
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:80: ';' expected
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:100: <identifier> expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:100: '{' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:100: not a statement
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:100: ';' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:110: illegal start of type
    [javac]     public void site2clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:110: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site2clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:110: ')' expected
    [javac]     public void site2clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:110: not a statement
    [javac]     public void site2clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:110: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site2clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:111: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map2zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:111: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map2zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:111: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map2zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:111: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map2zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:111: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map2zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:111: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map2zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:112: not a statement
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:112: ';' expected
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:132: <identifier> expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:132: '{' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:132: not a statement
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:132: ';' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:143: illegal start of type
    [javac]     public void site3clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:143: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site3clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:143: ')' expected
    [javac]     public void site3clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:143: not a statement
    [javac]     public void site3clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:143: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site3clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:144: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map3zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:144: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map3zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:144: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map3zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:144: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map3zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:144: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map3zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:144: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map3zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:145: not a statement
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:145: ';' expected
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:165: <identifier> expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:165: '{' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:165: not a statement
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:165: ';' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:176: illegal start of type
    [javac]     public void site4clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:176: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site4clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:176: ')' expected
    [javac]     public void site4clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:176: not a statement
    [javac]     public void site4clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:176: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void site4clickTest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:177: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:177: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:177: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:177: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:177: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:177: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick, String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext)
    [javac]                                                                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:178: not a statement
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:178: ';' expected
    [javac]             throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:198: <identifier> expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:198: '{' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:198: not a statement
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:198: ';' expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:212: illegal start of type
    [javac]     public void siteallClicktest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:212: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void siteallClicktest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:212: ')' expected
    [javac]     public void siteallClicktest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:212: not a statement
    [javac]     public void siteallClicktest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:212: ';' expected
    [javac]     public void siteallClicktest(String eventsLink, String browserType,
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:213: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick1, String casinoSiteclick2,
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:213: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick1, String casinoSiteclick2,
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:213: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick1, String casinoSiteclick2,
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:214: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick3, String casinoSiteclick4,
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:214: not a statement
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick3, String casinoSiteclick4,
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:214: ';' expected
    [javac]             String casinoSiteclick3, String casinoSiteclick4,
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:215: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map1zoomOut, String map2zoomOut, String map3zoomOut,
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:215: not a statement
    [javac]             String map1zoomOut, String map2zoomOut, String map3zoomOut,
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:215: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map1zoomOut, String map2zoomOut, String map3zoomOut,
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:215: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map1zoomOut, String map2zoomOut, String map3zoomOut,
    [javac]                                                           ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:215: not a statement
    [javac]             String map1zoomOut, String map2zoomOut, String map3zoomOut,
    [javac]                                                            ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:215: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map1zoomOut, String map2zoomOut, String map3zoomOut,
    [javac]                                                                       ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:216: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext) throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:216: not a statement
    [javac]             String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext) throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:216: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext) throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:216: not a statement
    [javac]             String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext) throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                                                  ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:216: ';' expected
    [javac]             String map4zoomOut, String mapZoomoutGettext) throws AssertionError {
    [javac]                                                                                ^
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcases/ArcusEventsTests.java:272: <identifier> expected
    [javac]         } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] 100 errors

[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAABb85aBtbiIQSGjNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjGvRM8xr8S/tCQ5PzfVL78ktUuDM0uMry+HiYGhoohBCqo8OT+vOD8nVc8ZQoMUMkAAI0hhAQAUXUdTXgAAAA==[0mBUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client-test/workspace/testcase_compile.xml:32: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE'
```

Thanks for you help,

Tyler

Comment: exceptions,stacktraces, more details please?

Comment: ant:  thanks for the reply, I added Jenkins build log above, I tried to format it correctly but looks like I was unsuccessful

Comment: is the ant build successful on it's own ? without jenkins?

Comment: ha, you have to excuse my newbness, this is my 2nd day working with Ant... I get the error: No suites, classes methods or jar file was specified

Comment: Disregard last comment:ant does not work from command line.. I am pretty sure that javac cannot see the libraries I import as dependencies in my src files, I have set my JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME directories.... but don't know how to fix it!

Comment: I don't have proper path to dependent .jars, gimmie a bit and ill get back to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this order

classpath -> fileset -> pathelement

instead of

classpath -> pathelement -> fileset